# No volume control in Nexuiz fullscreen mode

Tags: pulseaudio, games

While playing Nexuiz on my Ubuntu in fullscreen mode the volume control buttons on my laptop don't work at all, externally after minimizing the game increasing/decreasing the sound solves the problem but there is no in-game vol control?

Also when on headphones the game music plays on the laptop speakers as well as on the headphones!

What could the problem be? Is this a sound driver issue or x-org issue? its also happening with someone i know while playing Warzone2100 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: this problem is most likely not caused by your system but by the way the full screen client application (aka game) handles input events. If it just eats all events, even the ones it doesn't understand, then no input control events will pass and reach the underlying desktop to react to this button press. Like warl0ck suggests, you might be able to circumvent this by catching the event at a lower level. I experienced the same problem but mostly with older linux ports or badly ported games. Try for example [Team Fortress 2](http://www.teamfortress.com/), volume control should work.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use acpid to listen for your XF86 volume key events, and use amixer to set the volume manually, but you need to disable the original volume key listener to prevent "double volume change"

As I only know about how this could work with xfce4-volumed, here I will only provide the ACPID handler script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Default acpi script that takes an entry for all actions

set $*

case "$1" in
    button/volumeup)
        amixer sset Master 3+ # increase volume by 3%
        ;;
    button/volumedown)
        amixer sset Master 3- # decrease volume by 3%
        ;;
esac
```

You will need to find these part in your acpid script and put the axmier lines in.

[Read this link for details](http://c0debreak.blogspot.com/2012/08/let-volume-keys-work-everywhere.html)