# get fn+volume control working in xfce

Tags: xfce, audio-volume

I'm running xubuntu 12.10 (xfce 4.10) (on a lenovo thinkpad X121e) and the function (fn) + volume control do not change the actual output volume. they do something and a volume change is displayed, but It seems to be changing the "HDMI / DisplayPort" (digital stereo, whatever that means...?) but all music seems to be output to "analogue stereo" (whatever that means...?).
So what probably want is to remap fn+f1/f2 (the volume control keys) to the audio output (but any other ideas are very welcome too).

how on earth do I do that?

Several users seem to be facing a similar problem, but I have so far not found a sufficient solution, since they all seem to be referring to gnome and most of them address something like "system settings -> sound preferences" which doesn't exist in (my) xfce.

the closest answer I could find I think could be this:
[No volume control in Nexuiz fullscreen mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52441/no-volume-control-in-nexuiz-fullscreen-mode)
does that mean I need to enable or install or whatever acpid and if yes, where and under what name do I save that script? nowhere can I find any such lines.
help very welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I am running Arch Linux (with xfce) on a Lenovo W530 and xubuntu (with xfce) on a W500.
As I recall on xubuntu the volume keys worked out of the box. On Arch I had to set the keyboard shortcuts manually:

Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts

```
   amixer set Master +5%    ->    XF86AudioRaiseVolume
   amixer set Master -5%    ->    XF86AudioLowerVolume
```

`amixer` has to be installed, of course. While setting the shortcuts, you don't have to type the `XF86...` commands; just press the key (-combination) you want when creating new shortcut.

Comment: great work, thanks!

Since it worked in command line,
I mapped 
amixer -c 1 sset Master playback 2%+ to XF68raisevolume and
amixer -c 1 sset Master playback 2%- to XF68lowervolume

in the 'keyboard -> application shortcut' settings (by pressing the desired buttons)

now in command line it works, but the 'buttons' (fn+raise/lower volume) do not.

I tried mapping the command to a vacant button (winkey + '+' and winkey + '-' respectively)

it works.

I suspect that I have to get rid of the "original" mapping, or, while I'm at it, edit it (which is what I've been looking for originally)
But how?

Comment: sorry this looks awful - don't know how to break lines in comments.

Comment: It' been a while... have you got it working?

Comment: Is this command working for you in the terminal  
amixer -c 1 sset Master playback 2%+  
Are you sure it's card number 1? For me it works with  
amixer -c 0 sset Master playback 2%+

Comment: I also didn't succeed to add line breaks :)
According to [Stackexchange Markdown Help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) two spaces it the end of a line should do it. Doesn't seem to work here...